# How do I use Rayon with an existing iterator?

Tags: rust, rayon

I turn a regex into a `HashSet` after doing some filtering. I am trying to use it with Rayon, but I can't figure out how to make Rayon work with an existing iterator without converting it to a vector first. Is this possible?

```
let re = Regex::new("url=\"(?P<url>.+?)\"").unwrap();
let urls: HashSet<String> = re.captures_iter(&contents)
    .map(|m| Url::parse(m.name("url").unwrap().as_str()))
    .filter(|parsed_url| parsed_url.is_ok())
    .map(|parsed_url| parsed_url.unwrap())
    .filter(|parsed_url| parsed_url.has_host())
    .map(|parsed_url| parsed_url.into_string())
    .collect();
```

Comment: `par_iter` as stated in the doc?

Comment: I tried that but got the following error:

error[E0599]: no method named `par_iter` found for type `regex::CaptureMatches<'_, '_>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:24:58
   |
24 |  let urls: HashSet<String> = re.captures_iter(&contents).par_iter()
   |                                                          ^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `par_iter` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `regex::CaptureMatches<'_, '_> : rayon::iter::IntoParallelRefIterator`

Answer (score 18):

This is possible now with [`ParallelBridge`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.0.3/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelBridge.html):

```rust
use rayon::iter::ParallelBridge;
use rayon::prelude::ParallelIterator;
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;

let rx = {
    let (tx, rx) = channel();

    tx.send("one!");
    tx.send("two!");
    tx.send("three!");

    rx
};

let mut output: Vec<&'static str> = rx.into_iter().par_bridge().collect();
output.sort_unstable();

assert_eq!(&*output, &["one!", "three!", "two!"]);
```

Comment: Note that you can use `rayon::prelude::*` to get traits such as `ParallelBridge` and `ParallelIterator` automatically. (It might be a matter of taste, though, but I find that naming the _traits_ manually doesn't improve readability of the module.) Also, rayon has [its own sort](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.3.1/rayon/slice/trait.ParallelSliceMut.html#method.par_sort_unstable) which you might want to use to sort the output by multiple cores.

Answer (score 10):

This answer is outdated for the last version of rayon. See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54201274/4498831) for a possible solution. It may or may not apply to your usecase.

---

Minimal reproduction:

```
extern crate rayon;

use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1_i32, 2, 3, 4].into_iter();

    // no method named `par_iter` found for type `std::vec::IntoIter<i32>`
    let _ = v.par_iter().sum();
}
```

You cannot do that. [Here](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.0.0/rayon/iter/trait.IntoParallelIterator.html#foreign-impls) are all the implementors of this feature, that are:

- BinaryHeap
- BTreeMap
- BTreeSet
- HashMap
- HashSet
- LinkedList
- VecDeque
- Option
- Range
- Result
- Slice/Array

I think that the reason why you cannot parallelize them is because iterators are lazy. An iterator is basically a current item `Option<Item>` and a `next()` method. You cannot split it in two parts to execute them in different threads.