# Simultaneous mutable access to arbitrary indices of a large vector that are guaranteed to be disjoint

Tags: vector, rust, thread-synchronization, rayon

### Context

I have a case where multiple threads must update objects stored in a shared vector. However, the vector is very large, and the number of elements to update is relatively small.

### Problem

In a minimal example, the set of elements to update can be identified by a (hash-)set containing the indices of elements to update. The code could hence look as follows:

```
let mut big_vector_of_elements = generate_data_vector();

while has_things_to_do() {
    let indices_to_update = compute_indices();
    indices_to_update.par_iter() // Rayon parallel iteration
       .map(|index| big_vector_of_elements[index].mutate())
       .collect()?;
}
```

This is obviously disallowed in Rust: `big_vector_of_elements` cannot be borrowed mutably in multiple threads at the same time. However, wrapping each element in, e.g., a `Mutex` lock seems unnecessary: this specific case would be safe without explicit synchronization. Since the indices come from a set, they are guaranteed to be distinct. No two iterations in the `par_iter` touch the same element of the vector.

### Restating my question

What would be the best way of writing a program that mutates elements in a vector in parallel, where the synchronization is already taken care of by the selection of indices, but where the compiler does not understand the latter?

A near-optimal solution would be to wrap all elements in `big_vector_of_elements` in some hypothetical `UncontendedMutex` lock, which would be a variant of `Mutex` which is ridiculously fast in the uncontended case, and which may take arbitrarily long when contention occurs (or even panics). Ideally, an `UncontendedMutex<T>` should also be of the same size and alignment as `T`, for any `T`.

### Related, but different questions:

Multiple questions can be answered with "use Rayon's parallel iterator", "use `chunks_mut`", or "use `split_at_mut`":

- [How do I run parallel threads of computation on a partitioned array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599334/how-do-i-run-parallel-threads-of-computation-on-a-partitioned-array)
- [Processing vec in parallel: how to do safely, or without using unstable features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644152/processing-vec-in-parallel-how-to-do-safely-or-without-using-unstable-features)
- [How do I pass disjoint slices from a vector to different threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33818141/how-do-i-pass-disjoint-slices-from-a-vector-to-different-threads)
- [Can different threads write to different sections of the same Vec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928051/can-different-threads-write-to-different-sections-of-the-same-vec)
- [How to give each CPU core mutable access to a portion of a Vec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49354237/how-to-give-each-cpu-core-mutable-access-to-a-portion-of-a-vec)

These answers do not seem relevant here, since those solutions imply iterating over the entire `big_vector_of_elements`, and then for each element figuring out whether anything needs to be changed. Essentially, this means that such a solution would look as follows:

```
let mut big_vector_of_elements = generate_data_vector();

while has_things_to_do() {
    let indices_to_update = compute_indices();
    for (index, mut element) in big_vector_of_elements.par_iter().enumerate() {
        if indices_to_update.contains(index) {
            element.mutate()?;
        }
    }
}
```

This solution takes time proportionate to the size of `big_vector_of_elements`, whereas the first solution loops only over a number of elements proportionate to the size of `indices_to_update`.

Comment: IMHO It is not possible in the `safe` rust, you should use `unsafe` rust.

Comment: If the compiler is not able to verify that an operation is safe, but you can proof that it is, using unsafe code can be a good choice. One option would be to wrap the objects in the vector in an `UnsafeCell`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach As far as I see, the `UnsafeCell` would still not be usable in a parallel iterator, since it's not `Sync`. I could make a custom type and `unsafe impl Sync` like it shows in the standard library documentation of `struct UnsafeCell`, but I'm not sure what responsibilities then fall onto my shoulders. If you feel comfortable with it, feel free to expand your comment to an answer.

Comment: Maybe this approach is useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70851207/286335

Comment: Thanks @cibercitizen1, when the slice contains values of atomic types (or of types for which atomic versions exist), that solution is indeed very applicable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the compiler can't enforce that mutable references to a slice elements aren't exclusive, [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) is pretty nice.

You can transform a `&mut [T]` into a `&Cell<[T]>` using [`Cell::from_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#method.from_mut), and then a `&Cell<[T]>` into a `&[Cell<T>]` using [`Cell::as_slice_of_cells`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#method.as_slice_of_cells). All of this is zero-cost: It's just there to guide the type-system.

A `&[Cell<T>]` is like a `&[mut T]`, if that were possible to write: A shared reference to a slice of mutable elements. What you can do with `Cell`s is limited to read or replace — you can't get a reference, mutable or not, to the wrapped elements themselves. Rust also knows that `Cell` isn't thread-safe (it does not implement [`Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html)). This guarantees that everything is safe, at no dynamic cost.

```
fn main() {
    use std::cell::Cell;

    let slice: &mut [i32] = &mut [1, 2, 3];
    let cell_slice: &Cell<[i32]> = Cell::from_mut(slice);
    let slice_cell: &[Cell<i32>] = cell_slice.as_slice_of_cells();
    
    let two = &slice_cell[1];
    let another_two = &slice_cell[1];

    println!("This is 2: {:?}", two);
    println!("This is also 2: {:?}", another_two);
    
    two.set(42);
    println!("This is now 42!: {:?}", another_two);
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. It looks like some features used here weren't available back when I asked the question (`as_slice_of_cells` was stabilized in august 2019), but at this point, this is probably the best answer.

Comment: So how would this be used in a multy thread context? Because it does not implement Sync the compiler complains `std::cell::Cell<i32> cannot be shared between threads safely`

Answer (score 7):

You can sort `indices_to_update` and extract mutable references by calling `split_*_mut`.

```rust
let len = big_vector_of_elements.len();

while has_things_to_do() {
    let mut tail = big_vector_of_elements.as_mut_slice();

    let mut indices_to_update = compute_indices();
    // I assumed compute_indices() returns unsorted vector
    // to highlight the importance of sorted order
    indices_to_update.sort();

    let mut elems = Vec::new();

    for idx in indices_to_update {
        // cut prefix, so big_vector[idx] will be tail[0]
        tail = tail.split_at_mut(idx - (len - tail.len())).1;

        // extract tail[0]
        let (elem, new_tail) = tail.split_first_mut().unwrap();
        elems.push(elem);

        tail = new_tail;
    }
}
```

Double check everything in this code; I didn't test it. Then you can call `elems.par_iter(...)` or whatever.

Comment: Note: iterating the `indices_to_update` in reverse order would avoid the index juggling. Apart from that, this seems to be the best way to do this in safe Rust.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the basis for a great solution. If I were to swap the HashSet for something that's easy to recursively split in two (e.g., binary tree, or perhaps `hibitset`), I could recursively split the vector in two using `split_at_mut`. This fits nicely onto Rayon's fork/join model. It'll probably be somewhat slower than a 'dirty' `unsafe` solution, but it does show that the safe abstraction offered by `Vec` gets us very far. I'm considering your submission as the answer, but I'll wait a bit longer to see if anyone else has neat insights like yours, Sven's or E_net4's.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a reasonable place to use `unsafe` code. The logic itself is safe but cannot be checked by the compiler because it relies on knowledge outside of the type system (the contract of `BTreeSet`, which itself relies on the implementation of `Ord` and friends for `usize`).

In this sample, we preemptively bounds check all the indices via `range`, so each call to `add` is safe to use. Since we take in a set, we know that all the indices are disjoint, so we aren't introducing mutable aliasing. It's important to get the raw pointer from the slice to avoid aliasing between the slice itself and the returned values.

```
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

fn uniq_refs<'i, 'd: 'i, T>(
    data: &'d mut [T],
    indices: &'i BTreeSet<usize>,
) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'d mut T> + 'i {
    let start = data.as_mut_ptr();
    let in_bounds_indices = indices.range(0..data.len());

    // I copied this from a Stack Overflow answer
    // without reading the text that explains why this is safe
    in_bounds_indices.map(move |&i| unsafe { &mut *start.add(i) })
}

use std::iter::FromIterator;

fn main() {
    let mut scores = vec![1, 2, 3];

    let selected_scores: Vec<_> = {
        // The set can go out of scope after we have used it.
        let idx = BTreeSet::from_iter(vec![0, 2]);
        uniq_refs(&mut scores, &idx).collect()
    };

    for score in selected_scores {
        *score += 1;
    }

    println!("{:?}", scores);
}
```

Once you have used this function to find all the separate mutable references, you can use Rayon to modify them in parallel:

```
use rayon::prelude::*; // 1.0.3

fn example(scores: &mut [i32], indices: &BTreeSet<usize>) {
    let selected_scores: Vec<_> = uniq_refs(scores, indices).collect();
    selected_scores.into_par_iter().for_each(|s| *s *= 2);

    // Or

    uniq_refs(scores, indices).par_bridge().for_each(|s| *s *= 2);
}
```

You may wish to consider using a bitset instead of a `BTreeMap` to be more efficient, but this answer uses only the standard library.

See also:

- [How do I use Rayon with an existing iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48922420/155423)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your contribution. I have two questions about your answer. First: my question was about _parallel_ iteration over the results. Your solution does not provide support for that as-is, and I don't see how to easily add that due to your use of `btree_set::range`. Can you clarify how you would suggest to make your solution (rayon-)parallelizable? Second — and perhaps also because of the need for parallelism — I wonder why this solution would be correct without the use of e.g. a `std::cell::Cell` to inform the compiler about unexpected mutability.

Comment: @Thierry yes, connecting the concepts would be useful, wouldn't it? I've updated with an example. Does that answer both pieces?

Comment: Thanks again. Storing the indices in a vector seems suboptimal, and I'm not sure what `par_bridge` does internally, but it looks like it too is not _as_ good as an optimal solution could be; _if_ it is safe to index as you propose. Inspired by your solution, I think manually checking the lower and upper bound of the indices, and then using the `par_iter` directly on the `BTreeSet` would be better. But that's because I envision the `BTreeSet` to play nice with rayon's fork/join semantics, but I honestly get lost in the code implementing the parallel iterator. Regardless, thanks, +1

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to pre-collect all the mutable pointers?, for example by implementing some sort of method that gives access to a mutable pointer of the array?

Answer (score 1):

I had a related issue. I needed to assign to arbitrary columns of a 2D array in parallel. I used ndarray myarray.[axis_chunks_iter_mut(nd::Axis(1), 1)](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.14.0/ndarray/iter/struct.AxisChunksIterMut.html) to iterate over every column.

Answer (score 0):

Since I've been dealing with a similar problem, here's my solution which I don't recommend using unless absolutely necessary:

```
struct EvilPtr<T> {
    ptr: *mut T,
}
impl<T> EvilPtr<T> {
    fn new(inp: &mut T) -> Self {
        EvilPtr { ptr: inp as *mut T }
    }
    unsafe fn deref(&self) -> *mut T {
        return self.ptr;
    }
}

unsafe impl<T> Sync for EvilPtr<T> {}
unsafe impl<T> Send for EvilPtr<T> {}
```

Now you can do:

```
let indices: [usize; 10] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let mut arr: [i32; 10] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
let e = EvilPtr::new(&mut arr[0]);
unsafe {
    indices.par_iter().for_each(|x: &usize| {
        *e.deref().add(*x) += *x as i32;
    });
}
println!("{:?}", arr);
```

If you absolutely need to do this, I recommend you bury it under some user friendly interface, where you can be sure no error can occur.

Comment: This code produces errors when run in Miri: error: *Undefined Behavior: no item granting read access to tag <untagged> found in borrow stack* / *this indicates a potential bug in the program: it performed an invalid operation, but the rules it violated are still experimental*.

Comment: Only tested it on my windows machine using rust 1.47. Yields the expected results.

Comment: Yes, that’s one of the possible outcomes of undefined behavior. Another equally valid outcome is that your disk is erased.

Comment: Why is this undefined behavior? all I've done is create a mutable pointer and convince the compiler it's safe to share across threads. As far as I know, undefined behavior can only arise in this context if you point the pointer at something out of bounds.

Comment: @Adam No it is not. Rust has strict (and complicated) aliasing rules, that you must always follow.