# How to create an iterator that allows mapping indices to mutable items in a slice

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime

I have a slice of items and a slice of indices into the first slice, essentially giving me a sub-group of items that I want to modify. To iterate over the items and manipulate them I can create the following helper function.

```rust
fn process_things_by_index_loop<T>(things: &mut [T], indices: &[usize], f: &dyn Fn(&mut T)) {
    for &ix in indices {
        let t = &mut things[ix];
        f(t);
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I would actually just like to get an iterator over the items so I can apply, e.g., a filter to them before further processing.

It looks like this could just be a mapping of indices to items like so:

```rust
fn iterate_thigns<'a, T>(
    things: &'a mut [T],
    indices: &'a [usize],
) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a mut T> {
    indices.iter().map(|&ix| -> &mut T { &mut things[ix] })
}
```

This can't work of course, since I could have the same index twice in the indices slice and when collecting the iterator I would create two mutable references to the same item. So this gives appropriately a life-time error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
 --> src\main.rs:4:47
  |
4 |     indices.iter().map(|&ix|->  &mut T { &mut things[ix]})
  |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^
  |

error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
 --> src\main.rs:4:47
  |
4 |     indices.iter().map(|&ix|->  &mut T { &mut things[ix]})
  |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime '_ as defined on the body at 4:24...
 --> src\main.rs:4:24
  |
4 |     indices.iter().map(|&ix|->  &mut T { &mut things[ix]})
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
 --> src\main.rs:4:47
  |
4 |     indices.iter().map(|&ix|->  &mut T { &mut things[ix]})
  |                                               ^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 3:19...
 --> src\main.rs:3:19
  |
3 | fn iterate_thigns<'a, T>(things: &'a mut [T], indices: &'a [usize]) -> impl Iterator<Item=&'a mut T>{
  |                   ^^
  = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
          expected &mut T
             found &'a mut T
```

This also means the return type probably can't be a simple `Iterator` at all.

This issues seems also related to [this blog post from 2013 on "Iterators yielding mutable references"](https://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2013/10/24/iterators-yielding-mutable-references/), which states that no standard solutions for this pattern exist yet.

There is also a related question [asking about mutable multi threaded access to the content of a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55939552/simultaneous-mutable-access-to-arbitrary-indices-of-a-large-vector-that-are-guar), but I am really interested in a single threaded, iterator-like solution, which might even allow indices to repeat.

So, is there something that enables an iterator-like interface for sequential iteration of the items indicated by the indices?

Comment: I would take a set of indices instead of a slice (to guarantee uniqueness) and use unsafe code.

Comment: I just added a note about a blog post that also mentions an unsafe solution. For my specific use case going through a set might actually work quite well.

Comment: Or you can keep the slice and have a policy about the duplicates: either return an error or ignore the other times an index appears.

Comment: I guess with a set you could even just reverse iteration (iterate the things and check whether the item's index is in the set) and do it all safely.

Comment: ...but that is a lot slower. Quick benching shows a slowdown of about 50x compared to the loop solution.

Comment: How is that possible? Do you have a code example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197942/discussion-between-michael-mauderer-and-french-boiethios).

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Simultaneous mutable access to arbitrary indices of a large vector that are guaranteed to be disjoint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55939552/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster I have addressed the difference in the desired outcome in the question.

Comment: The question is about multithreaded, yes, but none of the answers are. Please review the **answers** and see if they answer your question.

Comment: *which might even allow indices to repeat* — absolutely 100% not possible and would lead to memory unsafety. [How can I create my own data structure with an iterator that returns mutable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25730586/155423). See also [How do I write an iterator that returns references to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30422177/155423)

Comment: I think what I had in mind was a somewhat restricted iterator, that, e.g., only allows chaining of `for_each` and not "collect", thus avoiding the issue of multiple concurrent mutable references. But I guess then the answer is that something like that just doesn't exist and needs workarounds like proposed in those answer (and my question)

Comment: Actually this is what I was looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30422716/1175813 "Streaming iterators"

Comment: So you'd be happy marking this as a duplicate of the streaming iterators Q?

Comment: Sure, go for it.