# How to use rayon to update a personal struct containing an Array in Rust

Tags: rust, rayon, rust-ndarray

## CONTEXT

### General overview

(Here is the [github page](https://github.com/payasson/minimal_example_rust_problem) with the minimal example of my problem, and the [page](https://github.com/payasson/pfbox) of my whole project)
I'm very new to rust and I'm trying to simulate the behavior of a fluid in Rust. This is easy: computing large arrays with some functions for each timestep.

I'd like to parallelize the computations done each timestep using rayon. But the compiler doesn't want me to access a mutable struct containing an Array that I want to modify, even if I'm sure that each modification will be on different places in the array: which assure me that it's safe. (I think?).

So my question is: should I use unsafe rust in here? If so, how?
And: is it possible to make Rust understand that it's safe, or to do it properly without unsafe rust?
I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55939552/simultaneous-mutable-access-to-arbitrary-indices-of-a-large-vector-that-are-guar) which kind of resembled my problem, but couldn't find a way to use the solution for my problem.

I also tried to put `unsafe {...}` keywords everywhere, but the compilator still complains...

You may only need to read "Structs" subsection to understand the problem, but I will also put a "Function" subsection, in case it can be important. If you think it might not be necessary, you can skip to "Main function" subsection.

### Structs

Here are my structs:
I'd like to keep them that way, as they would give me (I think) more flexibility with setters/getters, but I'm open to change the way it's implemented right now.

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct vec2D {pub x: f64, pub y: f64}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
 struct ScalarField2D {
     s: Array2<f64>,
}    

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
 struct VectorField2D {
     x: ScalarField2D,
     y: ScalarField2D
}

impl ScalarField2D {

     // also a constructor new() but not shown for simplicity

     fn get_pos(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> f64
    {return self.s[[y,x]];}

    fn set_pos(&mut self, x: usize, y: usize, f: f64)
    {self.s[[y,x]] = f;}
}

impl VectorField2D {

     // also a constructor new() but not shown for simplicity

     fn get_pos(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> vec2D
    {let vec_at_pos = vec2D {
        x: self.x.get_pos(x, y),
        y: self.y.get_pos(x, y)};
     return vec_at_pos;}

    fn set_pos(&mut self, x: usize, y: usize, vec: &vec2D)
    {self.x.set_pos(x, y, vec.x);
     self.y.set_pos(x, y, vec.y);}

}
```

### Function

Here is my function: which takes a ScalarField2D struct, and computes a vector called the "gradient" at a particular position of the ScalarField2D array, and then returning this vector as a "vec2D" struct.

```
// computes the gradient of a scalar field at a given position
fn grad_scalar(a: &ScalarField2D,
               x: i32, y: i32,
               x_max: i32, y_max: i32) -> vec2D
{
    let ip = ((x+1) % x_max) as usize;
    // i-1 with Periodic Boundaries
    let im = ((x - 1 + x_max) % x_max) as usize;
    // j+1 with Periodic Boundaries
    let jp = ((y+1) % y_max) as usize;
    // j-1 with Periodic Boundaries
    let jm = ((y - 1 + y_max) % y_max) as usize;
    let (i, j) = (x as usize, y as usize);

    let grad = vec2D {
        x: (a.get_pos(ip, j) - a.get_pos(im, j))/(2.),
        y: (a.get_pos(i, jp) - a.get_pos(i, jm))/(2.)};
        
    return grad;
}
```

### Main function

Here is my problem:
I try to iterate over all the possible x and y using (0..x_max).into_par_iter() (or y_max for y), compute the gradient associated with each position, and then set the value to the ScalarField2D struct using the set_pos method... Here is the main function, and the import commands, and I will show you the error message I get in the next subsection

```
use ndarray::prelude::*;
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {

    let (x_max, y_max) = (2usize, 50usize);
    let (x_maxi32, y_maxi32) = (x_max as i32, y_max as i32);

    let mut GD_grad_rho = VectorField2D::new(x_max, y_max);
    let mut GD_rho = ScalarField2D::new(x_max, y_max);    

    let x_iterator = (0..x_max).into_par_iter();
    x_iterator.map(|xi| {
        let y_iterator = (0..y_max).into_par_iter();
        y_iterator.map(|yi| {

            // unsafe here?
            GD_grad_rho
                .set_pos(xi, yi,
                         &grad_scalar(&GD_rho,
                                      xi as i32, yi as i32,
                                      x_maxi32, y_maxi32));
            
        });});
}
```

### Error message

Here is the compilation error I get

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `GD_grad_rho` as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a `Fn` closure
   --> src/main.rs:104:13
    |
104 | /             GD_grad_rho
105 | |                 .set_pos(xi, yi,
106 | |                          &grad_scalar(&GD_rho,
107 | |                                       xi as i32, yi as i32,
108 | |                                       x_maxi32, y_maxi32));
    | |__________________________________________________________^ cannot borrow as mutable

error[E0596]: cannot borrow `GD_grad_rho` as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a `Fn` closure
   --> src/main.rs:101:24
    |
101 |         y_iterator.map(|yi| {
    |                        ^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
...
104 |             GD_grad_rho
    |             ----------- mutable borrow occurs due to use of `GD_grad_rho` in closure

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0596`.
error: could not compile `minimal_example_para` due to 2 previous errors
```

If you want the complete thing, I created a [github repo](https://github.com/payasson/minimal_example_rust_problem) with everything in it.

### Tests after susitsm answer

So I did something like this:

```
use ndarray::prelude::*;
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn grad_scalar(a: &Array2<f64>,
          i: usize, j: usize) -> (f64, f64)
{
    let array_shape = a.shape();
    let imax = array_shape[0];
    let jmax = array_shape[1];

    // i-1 with Periodic Boundaries
    let ip = ((i + 1) % imax);
    // i-1 with Periodic Boundaries
    let im = ((i + imax) - 1) % imax;
    // j+1 with Periodic Boundaries
    let jp = ((j + 1) % jmax);
    // j-1 with Periodic Boundaries
    let jm = ((j + jmax) - 1) % jmax;

    let grad_i = (a[[ip, j]] - a[[im, j]])/2.;
    let grad_j = (a[[i, jp]] - a[[i, jm]])/2.;

    return (grad_i, grad_j);
}

fn main() {

    let a = Array::<f64, Ix2>::ones((dim, dim));

    let index_list: Vec<(_, _)> = (0..a.len())
        .into_par_iter()
        .map(|i| (i / a.dim().0, i % a.dim().1))
        .collect();

    let (r1, r2): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = (0..a.len())
        .into_par_iter()
        .map(|i| (index_list[i].0, index_list[i].1))
        .map(|(i, j)| grad_scalar(&a, i, j))
        .collect();

    let grad_row = Array2::from_shape_vec(a.dim(), r1).unwrap();
    let grad_col = Array2::from_shape_vec(a.dim(), r2).unwrap();

}
```

Which gives me the result I want, even though I wanted to access the values through my Structs. Which is not exactly what I want but we're getting closer
But I wonder about the efficiency for more arrays, I'll post a separate question for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```rust
use ndarray::Array2;
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let a: Vec<u64> = (0..20000).collect();
    let a = Array2::from_shape_vec((100, 200), a).unwrap();

    let stuff = |arr, i, j| (i + j, i * j);
    let (x, y): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = (0..a.len())
        .into_par_iter()
        .map(|i| (i / a.dim().0, i % a.dim().1))
        .map(|(i, j)| stuff(&a, i, j))
        .collect();
    let grad_x = Array2::from_shape_vec(a.dim(), x);
    let grad_y = Array2::from_shape_vec(a.dim(), y);
    let grad_vector_field = VectorField2D {
        x: ScalarField2D { s: grad_x },
        y: ScalarField2D { s: grad_y },
    };
}
```

Or implement the [`FromParallelIterator<vec2D>`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/iter/trait.FromParallelIterator.html)

```rust
impl FromParallelIterator<vec2D> for VectorField2D {
    fn from_par_iter<I>(par_iter: I) -> Self
        where I: IntoParallelIterator<Item = T>
    {
        let (x, y): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = par_iter
            .into_par_iter()
            .map(|vec_2D| {
                let vec2D { x, y } = vec_2D;
                (x, y)
            })
            .collect();
        Self {
            x: ScalarField2D { s: Array2::from_shape_vec(a.dim(), x) },
            y: ScalarField2D { s: Array2::from_shape_vec(a.dim(), y) },
        }
    }
}
```

This will enable using `collect` for your type when using parallel iterators

```rust
let vector_field: VectorField2D = (0..a.len())
        .into_par_iter()
        .map(|i| (index_list[i].0, index_list[i].1))
        .map(|(i, j)| grad_scalar(&a, i, j))
        .collect();
```

Comment: I fiddled something to use your idea but I wonder: would it be possible to update more than one Array using this technique?

(I'll update my question) In my problem, I'm going to compute the gradient of many arrays.

I wonder if its more efficient to do a loop on the indices for each array I want to compute the gradient of, or if it is more efficient to do one big loop on ```i, j``` and computing each ```array[[i,j]]```?

Comment: Sorry, I used `something like this` because I didn't have much time. You can ofc construct your struct from my example. I will extend my answer with it

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer solves my problem, I will incorporate this and try it in my project
Cheers!